# Cannot start database after server restart

Tags: docker, neo4j

I have a Neo4J Enterprise server 4.0 running official docker image "neo4j:4.0-enterprise". The server has been up and running for more than a month with 3 configured databases. The server is being executed as:

```
docker run --rm \
   -v /home/neo4j:/data -v /var/log/neo4j:/logs \
   -e NEO4J_ACCEPT_LICENSE_AGREEMENT=yes \
   -e NEO4J_dbms_mode=SINGLE \
   -e NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/secure-password \
   -e NEO4J_dbms_memory_heap_initial__size=5100m \
   -e NEO4J_dbms_memory_heap_max__size=5100m \
   -e NEO4J_dbms_memory_pagecache_size=6900m \
   -p 7474:7474 -p 7687:7687 \
   --name neo4j \
   neo4j:4.0-enterprise
```

Executing a very simple CYPHER in the neo4j browser console was failing in one of the databases (sandbox) with the following error message:

```
MATCH (n:IdentityProviderType) SET n.protocol = n.value
```

```
Newly created token should be unique.
```

The database contains only 2 nodes with the label `IdentityProviderType`.

After a server restart `docker restart neo4j` the database failed to get online showing the following message after executing `:sysinfo`:

```
An error occurred! Unable to start database with name 'sandbox'
```

Stoping the Neo4J server and executing:

```
docker run --rm -it \
   -v /home/neo4j:/data \
   -e NEO4J_ACCEPT_LICENSE_AGREEMENT=yes \
   neo4j:4.0-enterprise \
   neo4j-admin check-consistency --database=sandbox
```

```
2020-01-29 15:32:57.724+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.s.f.RecordFormatSelector] Selected RecordFormat:StandardV4_0[SF4.0.0] record format from store /data/databases/sandbox
2020-01-29 15:32:57.726+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.s.f.RecordFormatSelector] Format not configured for store /data/databases/sandbox. Selected format from the store files: RecordFormat:StandardV4_0[SF4.0.0]
org.neo4j.token.api.NonUniqueTokenException: The PropertyKey NamedToken[name:protocol, id:86, internal:false] is not unique, it existed as null.
    at org.neo4j.token.TokenRegistry.checkNameUniqueness(TokenRegistry.java:199)
    at org.neo4j.token.TokenRegistry.insertAllChecked(TokenRegistry.java:174)
    at org.neo4j.token.TokenRegistry.setInitialTokens(TokenRegistry.java:64)
    at org.neo4j.token.AbstractTokenHolderBase.setInitialTokens(AbstractTokenHolderBase.java:46)
    at org.neo4j.token.TokenHolders.setInitialTokens(TokenHolders.java:59)
    at org.neo4j.consistency.ConsistencyCheckService.runFullConsistencyCheck(ConsistencyCheckService.java:230)
    at org.neo4j.consistency.ConsistencyCheckService.runFullConsistencyCheck(ConsistencyCheckService.java:158)
    at org.neo4j.consistency.CheckConsistencyCommand.execute(CheckConsistencyCommand.java:137)
    at org.neo4j.cli.AbstractCommand.call(AbstractCommand.java:60)
    at org.neo4j.cli.AbstractCommand.call(AbstractCommand.java:30)
    at picocli.CommandLine.executeUserObject(CommandLine.java:1743)
    at picocli.CommandLine.access$900(CommandLine.java:145)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2101)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2068)
    at picocli.CommandLine$AbstractParseResultHandler.execute(CommandLine.java:1935)
    at picocli.CommandLine.execute(CommandLine.java:1864)
    at org.neo4j.cli.AdminTool.execute(AdminTool.java:78)
    at org.neo4j.cli.AdminTool.main(AdminTool.java:59)
```

How can I recover from a database that fails to start?

I cannot find anything in the documentation that helps me troubleshoot this type of problems.

Thanks for your help,

Rogelio

Comment: Do you want to retain the copy of database?

Comment: Yes, I have a copy of the database, I had to restore a backup since the database no longer starts.

Comment: Can you manually delete the database volume, in addition to that remove docker image. Try to start from scratch.

Comment: Hi, I have done that many times, I even tried creating a new server, creating the database, shutdown the server, copying the database files and starting the server. Same results, the database files are corrupted. I cannot think that a database server cannot recover from such a problem, imagine that happens in production...

Comment: There is a unix mount /home/neo4j:/data. Did you deleted the neo4j directory before starting?

Comment: Thanks for your help, looking at the stack trace you can see that the database files are available to the server. Is there anyone from Neo4J support team that can provide an official answer to this problem. I do not feel comfortable putting the Neo4J 4.0 server on a production environment if I cannot find  a solution. We have been running 3.x in production for some time without a single problem under the startup license and planning to upgrade as soon as possible but found a show stopper.

Comment: @RogelioJ.Baucells Same problem here, 3.x is great, no problems at all. 4.x is full of bugs and should not be used in production, need drop the database from time to time.... definitely a show stopper.